# Draw over image javaFx

Tags: uiimageview, javafx, draw

I have an ImageView object stored into a scrollPane and I need to be able to draw over that image.Please give me some sugestions.I use javaFx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the solution in: [View of the application javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072108/view-of-the-application-javafx) for which there is some source code to [Create a pannable map background in JavaFX](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5032398)

[image]

The solution uses a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) to layer content over the image, but you could draw any node you like.