# Sidescrolling over image in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, horizontal-scrolling

I've wrapped my brain around a challenge for 2 days now. I am all empty for ideas, so I hope someone out there know how to do this.

I got inspired by Angela Caicedo's city app, from the website https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx, and trying to make a similar app-gui to show available rooms and lecture halls at my University.

I am using Java FX to build the gui, and I get the whole GUI printed out, which is a java fx pane with a image on it. What I want, however, is to just see a small part of the gui (the backgroundimage I am using is w:1500px h:500, so each part will be w:500px h:500px), then be able to push a button or a arrow (or similar) to move the window to the next step. On top of the image there is 3 panes with w:500px h:500px snapped to each other. Maybe this is a bad solution, considering all the pane-types Java FX has available.

So, what I need is a constrained viewer of sorts.

I've also used FMXL to build the GUI, having one FMXL document, one Controller and a css-file to handle the design.

I'm sure I've been everywhere on the internet by now, so I really hope someone has done this before in Java FX :)

Ok, here is some code example. The first sample works nice, but I want to implement the second example instead. I am reading on the TranslateTransition of JavaFX, but my efforts of trying to switch the code is hopeless..

1'st example (working, and is fading in and out of the fxml screen):

```
public boolean setScreen(final String name){
        if (screens.get(name) != null) {   //screen loaded
      final DoubleProperty opacity = opacityProperty();

      if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {    //if there is more than one screen
        Timeline fade = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(2000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                getChildren().remove(0);                    //remove the displayed screen
                getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));     //add the screen
                Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                  new KeyFrame(new Duration(2000), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
                fadeIn.play();
              }
            }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
        fade.play();

      } else {
        setOpacity(0.0);
        getChildren().add(screens.get(name));       //no one else been displayed, then just show

        Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
        fadeIn.play();
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!!! \n");
      return false;
    }
    }
```

Second example, the TranslateTransition I want to implement instead:

```
private final double IMG_WIDTH = 500;
    private final double IMG_HEIGHT = 500;

    private final int NUM_OF_IMGS = 3;
    private final int SLIDE_FREQ = 4; // in secs

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();


        Pane clipPane = new Pane();
        // To center the slide show incase maximized
        clipPane.setMaxSize(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
        clipPane.setClip(new Rectangle(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT));

        HBox imgContainer = new HBox();

        ImageView imgGreen = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("uib_01.jpg")));
        ImageView imgBlue = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("uib_02.jpg")));
        ImageView imgRose = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("uib_03.jpg")));

        imgContainer.getChildren().addAll(imgGreen, imgBlue, imgRose);
        clipPane.getChildren().add(imgContainer);
        root.getChildren().add(clipPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
        stage.setTitle("Image Slider");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        startAnimation(imgContainer);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void startAnimation(final HBox hbox) {

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> slideAction = (ActionEvent t) -> {
            TranslateTransition trans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1.5), hbox);
            trans.setByX(-IMG_WIDTH);
            trans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
            trans.play();
        };

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> resetAction = (ActionEvent t) -> {
            TranslateTransition trans = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), hbox);
            trans.setByX((NUM_OF_IMGS - 1) * IMG_WIDTH);
            trans.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
            trans.play();
        };

        List<KeyFrame> keyFrames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_IMGS; i++) {
            if (i == NUM_OF_IMGS) {
                keyFrames.add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(i * SLIDE_FREQ), resetAction));
            } else {
                keyFrames.add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(i * SLIDE_FREQ), slideAction));
            }
        }
        Timeline anim = new Timeline(keyFrames.toArray(new KeyFrame[NUM_OF_IMGS]));

        anim.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        anim.playFromStart();
    }
```

The screen should change on button click. I have this in a separate controller class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class roomAppController implements Initializable, ScreenController {
    private ScreenPane myScreenPane;


    @FXML
    public ImageView bldArw_1;
    public ImageView rmArw_1;

    @FXML
    private void handleExitButtonEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button is clicked");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleNextPageEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            if((ImageView)e.getSource() == bldArw_1) {
                myScreenPane.setScreen("buildingScreen");
            }
            if((ImageView)e.getSource() == rmArw_1) {
                myScreenPane.setScreen("roomScreen");
            }
            System.out.println("Clicked");
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenPane(ScreenPane screenPage) {
        myScreenPane = screenPage;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, may be an image and some code could help.

Comment: See the stack overflow question: [View of the application javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072108/view-of-the-application-javafx) and the related [sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5032398) which works by placing an image overlaid with controls into a pannable scroll pane.  Is this what you trying to do?  If not, you will need to edit your question to be more specific, i.e. supply an image and [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).