# JavaFX - Multiple lights on a dark background

Tags: image, javafx-8, effects, lighting

I'm attempting to create something like a minimap with JavaFX, i.e. a (darkened) background image with some circles layered on top of it. Some of these circles need to be able to shed light on the background, revealing a small part of it. The following figure shows what I am aiming at.

[image: Desired Result]

I have worked my way forward using [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074792/3856838), but at the moment, I am stuck because it seems that you can only set one instance of `javafx.scene.effect.Lighting` on the underlying `StackPane`.

I would really like to keep this as simple as possible and ideally only employ JavaFX. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding together `Circle`s filled with a `RadialGradient` on a `Pane` with black background using `BlendMode.LIGHTEN` and combining this with a `ImageView` containing the "map" using `BlendMode.MULTIPLY`:

```
private Circle circle;

// gradient with yellow in the center and black on the border
private final static RadialGradient GRADIENT = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop(0, Color.YELLOW), new Stop(1, Color.BLACK));

private void newCircle(Pane container) {
    circle = new Circle(50, GRADIENT);
    circle.setBlendMode(BlendMode.LIGHTEN);
    circle.setManaged(false);
    container.getChildren().add(circle);
}

private void setCirclePosition(MouseEvent event) {
    circle.setCenterX(event.getX());
    circle.setCenterY(event.getY());
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image(imageURL);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    Pane mask = new Pane();
    mask.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
    mask.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    mask.setOnMouseMoved(this::setCirclePosition); // move cricle with mouse

    newCircle(mask);

    // create new circle on mouse click
    mask.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        newCircle(mask);
        setCirclePosition(evt);
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane(imageView, mask);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: screenshot]